# Can I spend event tokens after an event has ended?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The Festival of the Four Winds is about to end, and I realized that I don't know whether I have to spend all my Favor of the Festival and Festival Tokens before then.

Will merchants taking the event currency remain in the game, or do I have to make my purchasing decisions under time pressure?

Comment: I have never played that game, but I am going to assume that you must spend the tokens before the event ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most living story chapters require you to spend your [tokens](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Token) before the event is over.

Some chapters have token traders that remain for a set duration after the event concludes. A good example of this is [Lionguard Lyns](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Lionguard_Lyns), who remained available for several months after the Lost Shores chapter that she accepted tokens from.

[Halloween](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Halloween) and [Dragon Bash](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dragon_Bash) recur annually and have a shared permanent trader: [Sonder the Seller](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sonder_the_Seller). [Wintersday](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Wintersday) also recurs annually, although the [Festival Lionguard](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Festive_Lionguard_(Gift_Exchange)) trader for ugly wool items is only available during Wintersday.

Additionally, any type of weapon claim ticket (as well as both types of [Fortune Scraps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fortune_Scrap)) can be traded at the permanently available [Black Lion Weapons Specialist](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Weapons_Specialist).

I recommend spending all of your [Festival Tokens](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Festival_Token) before the Festival of the Four Winds ends tomorrow. The traders will likely be unavailable after that. It's possible that we may see Festival Tokens return for a future festival, but not guaranteed.

**Update**: The [Festival Rewards Vendor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Festival_Rewards_Vendor) and [Sovereign Weapon Vendor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sovereign_Weapon_Vendor) did disappear at the end of that chapter, but have temporarily returned ([source](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/updates/Game-Update-Notes-July-15-2014)). They can be found at the Lion's Arch Grand Plaza or Divinity's Reach Crown Pavilion Waypoint.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on event, sometimes the merchants persist (like the scrap vendors), sometimes the vendors reappear after a while (like the frostivus festival, you could use currency from last year if you had any), but they are usually gone with the event. So... I suggest decide under pressure :). Is the safest bet, and since there are not that many rewards... is not so hard to decide.

Comment: Frostivus? You mean Wintersday?

Comment: Yeah... dunno why I remember it as Frostivus.

Comment: @Brian Frostivus was a DotA 2 event. Zozo got the number right!

Comment: Yeah... that's why I was stuck with that name :)). Srry 'bout that... I play waaaay to many games :P.